# Как подключить Google Analytics к своему приложению и увидеть подробную статистику по скачиваниям просмотрам и т.д?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать о том, как подключить Google Analytics к своему приложению и видеть подробную статистику по скачиваниям просмотрам и т.д?

Достаточно ли просто связать аккаунты Google Play и Analytics или нужно еще добавлять некоторые параметры в `AndroidManifest.xml` своего приложения?

Comment: Прояснитев вопросе что именно из документации по встраиванию аналитики вам не понятно и мы вам поможем.

Comment: Я хотел узнать о том, что чтобы подключить аналитику к приложению обязательно встраивать код AndroidManifest.xml своего приложения? Можно ли подключить аналитику не затрагивая сам код приложения, ведь приложение уже опубликовано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, подключить аналитику не пересобирая (т.е. добавить нужные файлы/строки и перекомпилировав, получив apk) проект и не выкладывая обновление в маркет, кое должны установить себе пользователи, невозможно.

Это из-за того, что библиотека аналитики должна работать вместе с программой и отсылать по сети данные о её использовании. И пока вы её в программу не встроите работать она не начнёт.

Comment: А статистика в консоли разработчика сильно отличается от статистики в аналитике? Что входит в показатели статистики в консоли google play?

Comment: Не должна. Но может отличаться если приложение с аналитикой будут ставить  в обхот маркета

Comment: А как часто статистика в консоли и в аналитике обновляется?

Comment: В консоли плохо обновляется. Однажды неделю не обнолялась. В аналитике должна почти в реальном времени работать

Comment: Ну и последний вопрос: можете  рассказать о Идентификаторе отслеживания и где его применить?

Comment: Про это не знаю. Ни разу не встраивал гугловую аналитику.